# What's the best solution to put word under another using css and html?

Tags: html, css

what's the best way to write this in html and css?
I tried using `div` for each, but i think it wasn't the best solution, if anyone have another better solution

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Please share your html and css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use inline elements (like `span`) to keep text in the same line and [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to place *decorative* content below.

```css
.team {
  position: relative;
}
.team::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <span class="team" title="Home">AC Milan</span>
  VS
  <span class="team" title="Away">Real Madrid</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo class to do this

```css
.main{
  font-size: 26px;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
}
.home:before {
  content: "HOME";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
}
.away:before {
  content: "AWAY";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<span class="text home">A.C</span> Milan Vs <span class=" text away">Real</span> Madrid
</div>
```